# Retrieve filename and ID with Google Drive API in C#

Tags: c#, file-system, api, web-services, google-drive

I am trying to retrieve filename and ID list with Google Drive API (the latest [Drive API version v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk) is used here) as a first step in order to analyze and manipulate these files on Google Drive. The experimental implementation is as below. (Note: `credentials.json` file is needed and the step to generate this file is [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials). )

**The experimental implementation**

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GoogleDriveFileManager
{
    class Program
    {
        static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveFileManager";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"Credential file saved to: {credPath}");
            }

            // Create Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
            listRequest.PageSize = 1000;
            listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";

            // List files.
            IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
                .Files;
            Console.WriteLine("Files:");
            Console.WriteLine($"file.Name{new String('\t', 6)}file.Id{new String('\t', 8)}file.ModifiedTime");
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{file.Name.PadRight(56)}{file.Id.PadRight(36)}{file.ModifiedTime}"
                        );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No files found.");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

If there is any possible improvement about potential drawback or unnecessary overhead, please let me know.

Comment: Which version of C# are you using? I'm asking it because for instance since C# 7.1 `async main` is [supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let me clarify that I'm not familiar with the Google Drive API. I've done some refactoring but I haven't tested it (just make it compile).

If I can assume you are using greater C# version than 8 then you can refactor your code like this:

```cs
using static {YourMainNamespace}.Constants;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential = await AuthorizeAgainstGoogleDriveAsync();
        IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = await GetFilesMetaInfoAsync(credential);
        DisplayFilesMetaInfoInTabularFashion(files);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAgainstGoogleDriveAsync(
        string sourceRelativePath = Authorize.RelativeFilePath.Source,
        string targetRelativePath = Authorize.RelativeFilePath.Target)
    {
        using var stream = new FileStream(sourceRelativePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            Authorize.Scopes,
            Authorize.User,
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(targetRelativePath, true));

        Console.WriteLine($"Credential file saved to: {Authorize.RelativeFilePath.Target}");

        return credential;
    }

    static async Task<IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>> GetFilesMetaInfoAsync(
        UserCredential credential,
        string applicationName = GetFiles.ApplicationName,
        int pageSize = GetFiles.PageSize,
        string fields = GetFiles.Fields)
    {
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName,
        });

        FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
        listRequest.PageSize = pageSize;
        listRequest.Fields = fields;

        var fileList = await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        return fileList.Files;
    }

    static void DisplayFilesMetaInfoInTabularFashion(IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Files:");
        Console.WriteLine($"{DisplayFiles.Name}{new string('\t', 6)}{DisplayFiles.Id}{new string('\t', 8)}{DisplayFiles.ModifiedTime}");

        if (files == null || files.Count <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DisplayFiles.NoFileMessage);
            return;
        }

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{file.Name,-56}{file.Id,-36}{file.ModifiedTime}");
        }
            
    }
}

static class Constans
{
    public static class Authorize
    {
        public const string User = "user";
        public readonly static string[] Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly };

        public static class RelativeFilePath
        {
            public const string Source = "credentials.json";
            public const string Target = "token.json";
        }
    }

    public static class GetFiles
    {
        public const string ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveFileManager";
        public const int PageSize = 1000;
        public const string Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
    }

    public static class DisplayFiles
    {
        private const string prefix = "file.";
        public const string Name = prefix + nameof(Name);
        public const string Id = prefix + nameof(Id);
        public const string ModifiedTime = prefix + nameof(ModifiedTime);
        public const string NoFileMessage = "No files found.";
    }
}
```

---

Let me give you some context for each part:

#### `Main`

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    UserCredential credential = await AuthorizeAgainstGoogleDriveAsync();
    IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = await GetFilesMetaInfoAsync(credential);
    DisplayFilesMetaInfoInTabularFashion(files);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

- I've made your `Main` [async](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) (supported since C# 7.1) to be able to use `async`-`await`
- I've split your logic into three smaller functions to make your `Main` **short and concise**

  - If the scope of the application is this small then you can use shorter names of course, like

    - `AuthorizeAsync`
    - `GetFiles`
    - `DisplayFiles`

#### `Constants`

```cs
using static {YourMainNamespace}.Constants;

...

static class Constans
{
    public static class Authorize
    {
        public const string User = "user";
        public readonly static ImmutableArray<string> Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly }.ToImmutableArray();

        public static class RelativeFilePath
        {
            public const string Source = "credentials.json";
            public const string Target = "token.json";
        }
    }

    public static class GetFiles
    {
        public const string ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveFileManager";
        public const int PageSize = 1000;
        public const string Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
    }

    public static class DisplayFiles
    {
        private const string prefix = "file.";
        public const string Name = prefix + nameof(Name);
        public const string Id = prefix + nameof(Id);
        public const string ModifiedTime = prefix + nameof(ModifiedTime);
        public const string NoFileMessage = "No files found.";
    }
}
```

- I've put all of the hardcoded values into a hierarchical structure

  - Because I'm unfamiliar with the domain I've organize them based on the usage
  - In normal cases you should organize them based on their semantics
- I've used `const` (which is implicit `static`) to prevent modification
- In case of `Scope` I've used `ImmutableArray` to prevent modification

  - Here I can't use `const` but it could (and should) be marked as `readonly`
- I've used `using static` to avoid prefixing with `Constants` each and every time

#### `AuthorizeAgainstGoogleDriveAsync`

```cs
static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAgainstGoogleDriveAsync(
    string sourceRelativePath = Authorize.RelativeFilePath.Source,
    string targetRelativePath = Authorize.RelativeFilePath.Target)
{
    using var stream = new FileStream(sourceRelativePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Authorize.Scopes,
        Authorize.User,
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(targetRelativePath, true));

    Console.WriteLine($"Credential file saved to: {Authorize.RelativeFilePath.Target}");

    return credential;
}
```

- I've made the *source* and *target* file paths configurable (but with default values)

  - If you wish you can make the same with *user* and *scopes*
- One can argue whether the `Console.WriteLine` should belong here or inside the `Main`

  - I've put it here to make the main as concise as possible
  - But from reusability point of view it should not belong here
- I've used [using declaration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using) (which is a C# 8 feature) to avoid the block operator (`{ ... }`)

#### `GetFilesMetaInfoAsync`

```cs
static async Task<IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>> GetFilesMetaInfoAsync(
    UserCredential credential,
    string applicationName = GetFiles.ApplicationName,
    int pageSize = GetFiles.PageSize,
    string fields = GetFiles.Fields)
{
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = applicationName,
    });

    FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
    listRequest.PageSize = pageSize;
    listRequest.Fields = fields;

    var fileList = await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();

    return fileList.Files;
}
```

- I've made this API call to async (`Execute` >> `ExecuteAsync`) to make use of the async non-blocking I/O
- I've declared the function with three optional parameters to be able to customize the request if needed
- I've realized that you are not making use of the `nextPageToken` but I did not remove it

  - I've assumed that the implementation of paging will be your next step

#### `DisplayFilesMetaInfoInTabularFashion`

```cs
static void DisplayFilesMetaInfoInTabularFashion(IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Files:");
    Console.WriteLine($"{DisplayFiles.Name}{new string('\t', 6)}{DisplayFiles.Id}{new string('\t', 8)}{DisplayFiles.ModifiedTime}");

    if (files == null || files.Count <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DisplayFiles.NoFileMessage);
        return;
    }

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{file.Name,-56}{file.Id,-36}{file.ModifiedTime}");
    } 
}
```

- This operation is tightly coupled to the request

  - It highly relies on the retrieved `fields`
  - So, it might make sense to it make more dynamic if needed
- I've used `new string` instead of `new String`

  - I suggest to read [this article](https://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2019/04/08/string-vs-String-is-not-about-style.html)
- I've reverted the `if` statement to use the **early exit** pattern

  - With this the main logic (`foreach`) is not indented
- I've also used the capabilities of string interpolation to avoid calls like `PadRight`